# Image not saving in public folder

Tags: android, laravel, react-native

I have an API, which I have created with Laravel, which accepts images from an Android device, I want to store the image received in `public/img` folder, but when I check the `public\img` folder the image isn't there, please what may be the issue, the image location even saves successfully in the db

```
public function SellPost(Request $request){
    $user = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->first();
    $goods = new Goods;
    $goods->name = $request->name;
    if($request->description){
    $goods->description = $request->description;
    }
    $goods->category_id = $request->cat_id;
    $goods->amount = $request->amount;
    $goods->quantity = $request->qty;
    $goods->seller_id = $request->user_id;
    if($goods->save()){ 
    if($request->hasFile('photo')){
    $path = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('img', $request->file('photo'));
    $filename = basename($path);
    //  Image::make($images->uri)->save(public_path('img/' . $filename));  
    $saver = new Images;
    $saver->product_id = $goods->id;
    $saver->location_url = 'img/'.$filename;
    $saver->save();
    //    $this->imagesUpload($goods->id, $request->photo);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Internal Server Error, Please try again Later'], 401);   
    }  
    };
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Goods Posted Successfully'], $this->successStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('img', $request->file('photo'));
```

with

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->putFile( public_path('img'), $request->file('photo'));
```

Had this issue at some point and that was how I resolved it.

Comment: It brings an error, `Impossible to create the root directory \\"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\sele\\\\storage\\\\app/public\\\\C:/xampp/htdocs/sele/public/img\\".",\n `

Answer (score 0):

I got 2 solutions for you

1 : In config/filesystems.php, you could do this... change the root element in public

```
'disks' => [
   'public' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
       'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
       'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
]
```

and you can access it by

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('filename', $file_content);
```

2: you can put the file path and try to save it.

```
$file = $request->hasFile('photo');
$file->store('toPath', ['disk' => 'public']);
```

goodluck